# jQuery with image carousel execute on click over image. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, ajaxform

I'm trying write a javascript to execute same steps after user click over a image get your id, username and password. After it, send to my script php where will executes my local script.
    But I don't know whats wrong, but even a click a some img get your id, fill the form my php script calls the back-end script the same times of the images clicked.

Some could me explain what i need to do o whats wrong?

Javascript

```
/*--------------------------------------------------*/
/*      BACKEND SCRIPT                              */
/*--------------------------------------------------*/
$('#loginform').hide();

$('#limpar').click(function hideOrder() {
    $('#resultado').hide();
});

$('img').click(function getIdImage(event) {
    id_image = (this.id);
    alert(id_image);
    // Form Login
    $('#loginform').show().submit(function formInfo() {
    login = $('#login').val();
    senha = $('#senha').val();   
    $("#status").show().html("<img src='images/ajax-loader.gif' alt='Consultando ...' />");
        $.post(
        'contact_form/validateUser.php',
            { target:id_image, username: login, password: senha }, 
                function getDataBack(data) {
                    if (data.error) {
                        $('#retorno').html(data.error);
                        $('#status').hide();
                    } else {
                    $('#retorno').html(data);
                    $('#imagem').attr('src', '/Onepage/screenshots/' + login + '.png');
                    $('#resultado').show();
                    $('#status').hide(); }
            }, 'json');
        return false;
        login = $('#login').val("");
        senha = $('#senha').val("");
        id_image = val("");
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php 
// Informations passes from form
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$target = $_POST['target'];
$retorno = array();

// Execute
$run = "/usr/local/run/parser";
$script = "/var/run/back/$target";

// Check if POST is not null
if ( ($username == "") && ($password == "") ) {
    $retorno['error'] = "Os campos email e senha sÃ£o obrigatÃ³rios.";
    echo json_encode($retorno);
    return false;
}
// Execute to via asynchronous process
try {
    exec("{$run} {$script} {$username} {$password} 2>&1", $output);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $retorno['error'] = "NÃ£o foi possivel acessar target!";
}
// Return Data if success
$retorno['success'] = $output;
echo json_encode($retorno);
?>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-10">
    <div id="status" style="display: none;"></div>
    <div id="resultado" data-animated="fadeInUp" class="col-lg-12 col-sm-offset-2">
        <div id="retorno"></div>
        <img id="imagem" />
    </div>
</div>`enter code here`
```

Comment: I'm a tad confused.  Your php script is called the same number of times as the image is clicked?  Because you have an ajax call nested within a click event, so that's expected.

Comment: @JYG, i wanna get the id image even that someone is clicked. After that show a login form, pass the fields username and password to my php script, validate same informations and pass again the values of username and password to my backend script in casperJS. That is it.

Answer (score 0):

You should give these specific images a classname so no other images can trigger the event by mistake. 
Secondly you could use the jQuery one OR on

```
$( ".imgclass" ).on( "click", function( event ) {
  alert( "This will be displayed only once." );
  $( this ).off( event );
  // The event will be removed for the specific image
});
```

Otherwise if you want your request to be triggered only once you should use .one

```
$( ".imgclass" ).one( "click", function() {
  alert( "This will be displayed only once." );
  // No images will be able to trigger the event
});
```

Source: https://api.jquery.com/one/